# Error message in Update Manager

Tags: apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)
>   [How do I fix “malformed line” errors in sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152184/how-do-i-fix-malformed-line-errors-in-sources-list)

I am getting an error message when I run the Update Manager:

```
E:Malformed line 59 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You should open /etc/apt/sources.list and report here the affected line (nr. 59)

Comment: Please add line 59 of sources.list to your question. If you don't know how to do this, type: `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`, go to line 59 and copy the whole line(copy line 58 and 60 too). Thank you

Comment: *In addition* to showing line 59 by itself, you should also add the entire contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` to your question (or at http://paste.ubuntu.com and include a link to it in your question). Seeing just the bad line in isolation is not always sufficient to figure out how things should best be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same error and had to remove the line 59 and 60 to solve the problem. Not sure if it affects any other update process. The contents of the line 59-60 are:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/lucid partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/lucid partner
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are mixing repositories from different distributions.

You should post your `sources.list` file or you can try this link, it might help you: [E:Malformed line 52 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (URI), E:The list of sources](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1873114)