#  "Malformed line 6" error in my /etc/apt/sources.list 

Tags: apt, software-sources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)

I'm new to Ubuntu so I don't really know much yet. I encountered this problem while on the terminal:

```
E: Malformed line 6 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse) 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

What should I do? Help would be much appreciated.

Here's my `source.list`:

```
# /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ partner
/etc/apt/sources.list
```