# Malformed line in the source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse), dont let me use update manager

Tags: update-manager

Here is the error hope i can get some help, i show you the update manager and the line of the error, if you need something else just ask for it.

```
update manager error prompt:

An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.

Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:

'E:Malformed line 58 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse), E:The list of sources could not be read., E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.'

================================================================================
error line:

deb http:mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
```

Comment: sorry it was this one:
deb-src http://archive.conical.com/precise partner

Comment: conical? do you mean canonical

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)

Answer (score 4):

Your URL is mangled:

```
deb http:mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
```

should be:

```
deb http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
```