# Can't open Software Center or Update Manager

Tags: apt, software-center, update-manager

When I try to (not from terminal) the following error message opens up:

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.
Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:

'E:Malformed line 60 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)'
```

Using Ubuntu 12.04, thanks.

Edit: Went to line 60, this is what I found:

deb http://archive.canonical.com/precise partner

Edit: Commented the line out, software manager works fine now.

Comment: Please open /etc/apt/sources.list with gedit, go to line 60, copy the entire line and post it here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in your sources list.

To go straight to the sources list, open a Terminal and issue the command: `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Look for the mistake at line 60.

If you have any trouble copy and paste your sources list here so we can have a look.