# Can't open "ubuntu software center", "software updater", "software sources", "language support" Malformed line 56 in source list

Tags: 12.10, apt, software-sources, source

I get the following error:

> Could not initialize the package information
>
> An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.
>
> Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:
> E:Malformed line 56 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (URI parse), E:The list of sources could not be read., E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

I know that the problem is the **line 56 in source list**, but I did all that says in "*How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?*"
because it's a '[duplicate]' of my first question, but the problem remains even with each proposed solution, what else can I do?

When I type in the Terminal `gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` I get:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release i386 (20121017.2)]/ quantal main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted
deb-src http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted
deb-src http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe
deb-src http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe
deb http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe
deb-src http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal multiverse
deb-src http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal multiverse
deb http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates multiverse
deb-src http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src socio http://archive.canonical.com/ precisa
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
```

Obviously I must say that I'm new on this, so I will appreciate your help.

And thanks to -*Eliah Kagan*- to teach me how to put the '**sources.list**' it was exactly what I wanted to do in first place but I didn't know how to do it, Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the solutions there didn't help, then we'll definitely have to look at your actual `sources.list` file. So, please open it up in a text editor, copy its contents to the clipboard, *edit your question*, paste it in, format it with the `<$>` tool (so it appears correctly) and submit your edit.

Answer (score 1):

*Remove* the line before the last one:

```
deb-src socio http://archive.canonical.com/ precisa
```

Seems like you've edited it manually and made mistakes. This line does not indicate anything specific (`main`, `partner`, etc.), so I won't know what this line was supposed to be.

After removing and saving the file, update the packages sources, e.g. `sudo apt-get update`, or click *Check* in the System update manager.

*By the way, I don't see how the broader [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list) question does not cover this.*

Comment: I believe `socio` is Spanish for `partner`. Therefore, you may want to edit this to recommend uncommenting `deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner` a few lines up (as this will do what that malformed line was probably intended to do--enable source packages from the partner repository).

Comment: @EliahKagan If that is indeed so, and `precisa` means `precise`, then... this might be a translation issue which should never occur?

Comment: I bet that he followed a guide in a google translated web page ;).

Comment: @JavierRivera Ah yeah, that's fine for textual articles, but totally stuffs specific instructions to copy/paste.