# E: Malformed line 57 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)

Tags: 12.04, software-sources

Hi guys I've just got this error message when i opened update manager:

```
E: Malformed line 57 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
```

any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: I think that you will find the solution [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/78951/62483). Just to mention, you should show all the content of that file to solve that. Anyway, this post will probably closed as a duplicated soon. If that post doesn't address with your issue, you should tell us.