# I can't remove a malformed line from my sources.list.d?

Tags: package-management, dependencies, software-sources

I tried to follow a poorly explained tutorial on how to install the Opera browser from the terminal. After this failed, I have not been able to get to the Software Center or the Software Updater. I also get this error message:

```
An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu
or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The error message was:
'Error: Opening the cache (E:Malformed line 1 in source list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list (dist), E:The package lists or
status file could not be parsed or opened.)'. This usually means that
your installed packages have unmet dependencies.
```

Yes, I've seen all the other "malformed line" threads, but nothing is helping. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am running 13.04.

Comment: Of course, typos in the quoted text are mine. I know it's not a rick-click. I couldn't copy and paste the message.

Comment: Did you already try this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/285015/e-malformed-line-57-in-source-list-etc-apt-sources-list-dist-parse/285018#285018, of course, refer to your sources.list.d/opera.list file.

Comment: Include the link given to you after this command: `sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list | pastebinit`.  You may need to install pastebinit with `sudo apt-get install pastebinit`

Answer (score 0):

First install gksu

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

Then open the file with gedit

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list
```

You can post the line here for review or comment it out by adding a # in the front

Comment: This is the line:

deb http://deb.opera.com/opera

I'm still getting the error after I added the #

Comment: The problem seems to be resolved. Thank you very much.