# Why do I get 404 error on .canonical.com on some archive servers?

Tags: apt, updates, package-management

I've been having a broken package problem for a fair amount of time now, and it was giving me trouble earlier when I was trying to install rvm. After some searching, I opened the software sources manager "gksu software-properties-gtk" and unchecked the archive.canonical.com repositories from "Other Software" and I no longer have any broken packages. Are these important repositories? Should I be worried about my installations health? I'm an Ubuntu noob, so this is worrying me.

It it matters, here were the "sudo apt-get update" errors:

```
 sudo apt-get update

Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                                                                
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                                                                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg                                                            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                                                                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg                                                           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg                                                         
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                                                                     
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main TranslationIndex                                                                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release                                                          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                                                                       
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                                                                       
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg                                                                   
Ign http://archive.canonical.com [distro] Release.gpg                                                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                                                                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release                                                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources                                                           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release                                                             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                                                                  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources                                                            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources                                                              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources                                                            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages                                                           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources                                                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources                                                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources                                                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages                                                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages                                              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages                                                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages                                              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages                                                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages                                               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages                                                 
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release                                                                           
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release                                                                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                                                           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages                                                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages                                                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages                                                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                                                            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages                                                      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages                                                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages                                                      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                                                         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex                                                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages                                               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex                                                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex                                            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex                                            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex                                                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex                                              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex                                                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources                                                          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources                                              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources                                                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources                                                    
Ign http://archive.canonical.com [distro] Release                                                                      
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                                                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                                                                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages                                             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages                                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages                                               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages                                             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en                                                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en                                              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages                                                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages                                              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages                                          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages                                              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex                                                 
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                                                                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en                                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex                                           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex                                           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex                                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted amd64 Packages                                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main amd64 Packages                                                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages                                           
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Sources                                                               
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner amd64 Packages                                                        
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages                                                         
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner TranslationIndex                                                      
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages                                                         
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                                                                
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                                                             
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                                                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                                                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                                                          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                                                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en                                          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages                  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                               
Ign http://archive.canonical.com [distro]/partner TranslationIndex                         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en                         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en                         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en                           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US          
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Err http://archive.canonical.com [distro]/partner Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
Err http://archive.canonical.com [distro]/partner amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
Err http://archive.canonical.com [distro]/partner i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en
Ign http://archive.canonical.com [distro]/partner Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.canonical.com [distro]/partner Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/[distro]/partner/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/[distro]/partner/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/[distro]/partner/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: which version of ubuntu did you are using?

Comment: the tag says 12.04 @AvinashRaj

Comment: The reason repositories are not found is that somehow he edited and change the actual distro release  to(sic) "distro". I am even more confused about both the 32bit and 64bit entries. Please clarify your question.

Comment: The url seems correct, he's probably using EOL.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, 64-bit. But considering this question was downvoted, just forget about it I suppose.

Comment: Done! Edited the original post.

Comment: Sorry, I switched over to Ubuntu half a year ago and am quite inexperienced. What do you mean by "switch to the Ubuntu main server"?

Comment: Originally it said "Server for United States" I changed that to Main Server and got similar results upon running "sudo apt-get update"

Comment: got an idea working on an answer....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Err http://archive.canonical.com [distro]/partner Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
Err http://archive.canonical.com [distro]/partner amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
Err http://archive.canonical.com [distro]/partner i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
```

the line that contains `[distro]` should be replaced with `precise` if you are running 12.04.

1. To edit the source list start by opening a terminal.
2. edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` with like `gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` and a gedit window of the file will open.
3. find the lines that say `deb http://archive.canonical.com [distro]/partner` and `deb-src http://archive.canonical.com [distro]/partner`
4. `deb http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner` and `deb-src http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner`

This should be six lines to edit according to your error.

[Source of commands](https://askubuntu.com/a/178539/10698)

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked great! By the way, what exactly are those archive.canonical repositories used for anyways?

Comment: @KyleSum in my source file it just says that is the software from Canonical's 'partner' repository. I don't know what packages those are. But do you have any updates to install now?

Answer (score 0):

In xubuntu 12.04 the flashplugin-installer fails. The ubuntu archive is accessed, the file it is seeking (the .orig.tgz flashplugin-installer tgz archive) exists, but the download stalls.

My method to fix this was to use synaptic as root and remove completely the flashplugin-installer from the apt system.

Then I went here: 
http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/download/?installer=Flash_Player_11.2_for_other_Linux_%28.tar.gz%29_32-bit&standalone=1

and downloaded the Adobe file offered, and did a manual install :

- unpack the archive
- read the Readme and follow it's directions
- Done.

The Readme is easily followed but requri3es to be executed as root using `su` - or using  `sudo`.
This fix is for the 32bit installer for xubuntu 12.04 update 4.