# Error while trying to update packages

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

yesterday I tried to install skype using the terminal, but I did something wrong because skype did not get installed and today, when I opened the pc, an error message appeared. It seems that while trying to update a package something went wrong. The message that appears says that I should update packages but when I try this appears(translated to english):

An irresolvable error has occured while initializing the packages information.
Inform of thus error to the update-manager and include the following message:

```
'E:Malformed line 60 in the source list /etc/apt/sources.list (analazing dist)'
```

This is a link to the text I get when I issue `gedit etc/apt/sources.list`

http://pastebin.com/9bdgXz7B

When writting: `sudo LANG=C apt-get update and sudo LANG=C apt-get check`  appears the following:

```
sudo LANG=C apt-get update 
E: Malformed line 60 in source list/etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

sudo LANG=C apt-get check
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

How to solve this?

Comment: You appear to have a mistake in line 60 of your sources list. From a Terminal issue the command: gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list  Can you copy and paste the result here, so we can see it?

Comment: I wrote the command: gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list on the Terminal but nothing appears... It does not seem to have done anything

Comment: `gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` You should see a window containing some text. Please, edit your question including that text.

Comment: I've done as you said but the text that appears is full of links and apparently I can't post it with the still low "reputation" I have on this page. How can I make it for you to see it?

Comment: Are you sure you cannot edit your question? o.O
Anyway, paste it on this site, and give us the link: http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Okey. This is the link: http://pastebin.com/9bdgXz7B Thanks

Comment: Could you do `sudo LANG=C apt-get update` and `sudo LANG=C apt-get check`. Also, you can [edit] your question and include the list any time.

Comment: I've done as you said and edited the results on the question above

Comment: @Ernest take a look at the question mentioned by Dumindu to understand what's happening with you. But the easiest fix for you is to delete the last 4 lines in your `sources.list` file (lines 63-66 in your pastebin link). Those are the malformed lines. The actual correct lines are already present above them (lines 56 and 57); all you need to do is remove the `#` at the beginning of those two lines. Save the file, and try to install Skype again. To edit you `sources.list` file, do `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: I tried reading the post  http://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list and I think I managed to solve the problem. I replaced the source.list with a new one created with the "ubuntu source list generator". Thank you everyone for your help.