# Package manager error

Tags: package-management, software-sources

I am getting a problem in Ubuntu as an error opening the cache, the list of software sources could not be read in my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and the package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened. I am new to Ubuntu, so I could not determine what is causing the problem. I also have a problem opening the Ubuntu Software Center and once I commented out line no. 56 stating `deb http://archive.canonical.com/raring partner`, Ubuntu Software Center opens OK. What could the problem be? I am including 4 lines from my sources.list file.

Source.list code on my line 56 is this:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/raring partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/raring partner  
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/raring partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/raring partner
```

Terminal output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py", line 629, in <lambda>
return (lambda data: callback(*data), user_data)
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line   261, in open
self._cache = apt.Cache(progress)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 105, in __init__
self.open(progress)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 150, in open
self._cache = apt_pkg.Cache(progress)
SystemError: E:Malformed line 56 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse),       E:The list of sources could not be read., E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
2014-01-22 11:27:29,685 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
```

Comment: Try to open software center via terminal and then post its output.

Comment: terminal output added

Comment: uncomment the 56th line in sources.list.Then open software center via terminal and post it's output.

Comment: 1st line in my source.list code is line no 56 it's already uncommented after uncommenting I'm getting this error

Comment: then delete the first line(which was same as 56th) from sources.list.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list

Comment: @minu, did you update the repositories after you made the changes to the sources? If not, check if my answer helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you made changes to the sources, you should update the `apt` so that the changes are recognized.

To do that, open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and enter the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and you should be done.

Comment: glad it helped.. and welcome to AskUbuntu...