# Malformed line in my sources list, how to resolve?

Tags: 12.04, updates, source

Before i start, i've tried the solution from this thread

[How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)

but unfortunately, the steps performed in that thread are already covered for me.
The error I'm getting is:

```
Malformed line 3 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudarchive-havana.list (dist)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I'm not too sure what is causing this but it won't allow me to use the ubuntu software center or perform any updates.

Here is the output from the malformed directory:

```
deb http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise-updates/havana main

deb-src http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise-updates/havana main

deb http://docs.openstack.org/havana/install-guide/install/apt/content/basics-packages.html
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of a solution please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is there a html page in your sources?

```
deb http://docs.openstack.org/havana/install-guide/install/apt/content/basics-packages.html
```

This does not belong in sources.list since it is not of a normal format.

Compare it to the other 2 and you will see the sources.list needs 4 sections and there are only 2 on this like. It is missing `precise-updates/havana` and `main`

Comment: I'm not sure, whoever was working with this last has been since let go, i'll remove it and see how i get on, cheers

Comment: @JayFitz it will work when removed :)

Comment: It worked a charm, thanks for the help, ill choose your answer (have to wait 10 minutes) :P

Answer (score 1):

The last line doesn't look right, I've never seen a ppa source ending as "something.html" so you could try commenting it and leaving the file like this:

```
deb http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise-updates/havana main
deb-src http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise-updates/havana main
#deb http://docs.openstack.org/havana/install-guide/install/apt/content/basics-packages.html
```

To edit the file, open a terminal and type this:

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudarchive-havana.list
```

Then, try to run an update again.