# archive.ubuntu.com Repository Error?

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

I am new to Ubuntu and excuse me if this is a quick fix. I am having issues running `apt-get update` and the error message that repeatedly comes up is:

```
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                   
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                              
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                        
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages          
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                       
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Sources                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages    
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/binary-i3836/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have tried removing the sources.list file and then replacing it by using the command "software-properties-gtk" but it doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't think there is anything to do here. Just try again in a few hours, it should fix itself.

Comment: It has not fixed it self. Any other ideas?

Comment: likely related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list

Comment: Don't think it's a one line issue. I comment out every deb line (deb-src has no issues) and then apt-get update works fine. I uncomment one deb and that line will produce an issue. For example I will comment out "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty restricted main universe multiverse" then get : "W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/binary-i3836/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead."

Comment: Does this have something to do with the binary-i3836 showing up? I know i386 (not i3836) is a type of architecture

Answer (score 1):

It seems like I had accidentally added an incorrect foreign architecture to my computer when using the "dpkg --add-architecture" command at a previous date. Below is the **incorrect** command I had entered:

> sudo dpkg --add-architecture i3836

That is why binary-i3836 was a reoccurring issue. I used the command below to fix the issue:

> sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i3836

I can use sudo apt-get update fine now.