# apt-get update malformed line

Tags: command-line, apt, updates

when i typed sudo apt-get update in terminal, it gave me this error:

```
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-latest.list (dist)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I looked into gazebo-latest.list file. there is a line

```
deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu quantal main
```

How can i fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

First of all Quantal is an [end of life Ubuntu release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) and not supported now, So upgrade your system into any supported release .

And solution for this problem is already discusseed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list), but putting a `/` after `ubuntu` in the `gazebo-latest.list` (i.e `deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu/ quantal main`) should also work.

(**Note:** you will still get error in update because of being an unsupported release so again upgrade your system into a supported release. See  [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)  )

Comment: im running ubuntu 14.04. not sure why quantal is in the file. Can you explain please?

Comment: If you are running 14.04, instead of `quantal` there should be `trusty` in your `gazebo-latest.list` file. It represent the version of ubuntu you are using while resynchronizing your software index with server (like when you use `sudo apt-get update`).  Edit this line to look like  `deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu/ trusty main`. It should work. Also mention that you are using 14.04 in your question by [editing](http://askubuntu.com/posts/576417/edit) it, so that it will not be marked as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, seems like i dont have permission to change the file. It says permission to write is owner root only. How can i log in as root ?

Comment: enter `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-latest.list` to open this file in editor. Edit it and press **Ctrl+o** to save and **Ctrl+x** to exit.