# Failed to update Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 LTS (Trusty Tahr)

Tags: 14.04, apt, multiverse

The following error is being encountered:

```
Atteint http://mg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en
Atteint http://mg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en  
2 964 ko réceptionnés en 24s (121 ko/s)                                        
W: Impossible de récupérer http://mg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Impossible de trouver l'entrée « multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages » attendue dans le fichier « Release » :  ligne non valable dans sources.list ou fichier corrompu

E: Le téléchargement de quelques fichiers d'index a échoué, ils ont été ignorés, ou les anciens ont été utilisés à la place.
```

command used:

```
apt-get update
```

source.list:

```
root@NOC-MONITORING:~# 
root@NOC-MONITORING:~# ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
root@NOC-MONITORING:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://mg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main multiverse restricted universe
deb http://mg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://mg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://mg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
root@NOC-MONITORING:~#
```

`rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf`  then  `apt-get update`

didn't solved it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)

Comment: i've update the  post and as you see those are the default repositories

Comment: Try with a different mirror, http://mg.archive.ubuntu.com is probably broken today.

Comment: uptated source.list to : [ fr.archive.ubuntu.com] but i still have the same error

Answer (score 1):

Your repository is out of date.

Via the GUI

1. Open the software center
2. *Edit **>** Software Sources...*
3. Find *Download from* and select *Main Server* from the drop down list
4. Close out of the software center
5. Do a `sudo apt-get update`

Via the CLI

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to reflect this:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main multiverse restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Some of the mirrors break. I live in Pakistan, and the mirror here hasn't worked for years. I use the Main Server myself.

Comment: Since it is an ubuntu server, i can only update from command line (/etc/apt/sources.list).
i've try with mirrors: us, fr ,mg and i have the same result.

Comment: @Lita `sudo perl -pe 's/^(deb\shttp:\/\/)mg\./$1/g;' -i /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @Lita, I've updated the answer with instructions on how to edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: @amingilani Still the same error..., i've also tryed with fresh install of Trusty Tahr and i have the same error.
are you on trusty  Tahr ?  if so, could you try an  `apt-get update`?