# I have had this red circle with the white icon

Tags: dependencies, software-sources

I have had this red circle with the white icon in the top right corner for a while now, and the specific message is:

```
An error occurred.  Please run Application Manager from the Right
Click Menu or apt-get to see what is wrong.
```

The error message was:

```
Unknown error'<class SystemError'>' (E:malformed line in source list
etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partnerlist (dist_parse))'.  This
usually means your installed packages have unmet dependencies'
```

I would like to get some help with this error?

Thank you!
Susan

Comment: try the suggestions given in http://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list

Answer (score 0):

I have had this error before so i ran software updater and then it said cannot find repository information, after a few min an update came up and i ran the update, after that everything went back to normal.