# Just installed synaptic and was sent back the following message when i attempted to open it

Tags: synaptic

```
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list (dist parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
Go to the repository dialog to correct the problem.
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

Help?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list (dist parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: This is what you're looking for: http://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list

Comment: @DevRobot good job you found the existing post for the same problem/solution. Better would be mark this one as duplicate. :-)