# Making and deleting deb files in sources.list.d dir. Permissions issue

Tags: permissions

I put a file into my `sources.list.d` dir and is not formated correctly. I get an error about `malformed line in source list '/etc/apt/source.list.d/precise-R.list' (dit parse)`. I forgot to put the `#deb ...` line. I tried to remove but I am denied permission. How do I get rid of that file?

I am new to Ubuntu precise and trying to put a deb file into `sources.list.d` dir but do not know how. At terminal I used:

```
sudo cp /home/steve/Steve1/precise-R.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/precise-R.list
```

And got the file in to the dir and now I cannot get out. Anytime I try other method to put this file into `sources.list.d` and save I am denied -- I do not have permission. How do I set the permission so I can make deb files correctly next time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)

Comment: Use `sudo vim /etc/apt/source.list.d/precise-R.list`, then `insert` for start typing, `:wq` for save and quit, or `:q!` quit without saving.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `sudo` - use the command `sudo` before the command you want to execute to run it with administrator privileges.

To remove the malformed line in `precise-R.list` enter the following command into the terminal:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/source.list.d/precise-R.list
```

To remove the file:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/source.list.d/precise-R.list
```