# Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file

Tags: package-management, updates, software-sources

I'm kinda new to this website so I don't know the policies, but I really need some help with an ongoing issue that has become quite annoying.
I moved from Ubuntu 14.04 to Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela (I personally prefer Linux Mint, please don't blame me)
Anyway, the thing is that everytime I tried to update any package or run a normal update process I get this annoying error message:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'universe/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I did some research but none of the solutions provided in those websites cfixed the problem. So I was wondering if anyone here might help me out to fix this problem. I know I can reinstall Mint again from the thumbdrive and start over, but if you're like me (after several days polishing your distro and having all the applications you need to work in Linux) you'll know it's aggravating to reinstall again without finding a solution first, and I know there's gotta be one. I'm just not that expert at Linux yet but I love it and switching from Windows was not easy at the beginning, but now I love Linux and don't want to go back.

Please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)

Comment: I followed all the steps but still got the same error message when updating.

Comment: what's the error?