# sudo apt-get update not working Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, skype

Whenever I put in the command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It returns:

```
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security InRelease
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid InRelease
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security Release.gpg [933 B]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates InRelease                       
Ign http://archive.canonical.com vivid InRelease                     
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security Release [63.5 kB]    
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports InRelease                 
Ign http://archive.canonical.com vivid InRelease                           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid Release.gpg       
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates Release.gpg [933 B]
Hit http://archive.canonical.com vivid Release.gpg
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports Release.gpg             
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main Sources [26.4 kB]
Hit http://archive.canonical.com vivid Release.gpg                             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid Release                                 
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted Sources [28 B]      
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates Release [63.5 kB]             
Hit http://archive.canonical.com vivid Release                              
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe Sources [12.3 kB]     
Hit http://archive.canonical.com vivid Release                                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports Release  
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main Sources [59.1 kB]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted Sources [28 B]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe Sources [26.7 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/universe Sources
Fetched 253 kB in 4s (62.5 kB/s)        
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid-security/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid-updates/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'partner/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid-backports/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/vivid/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'partner/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Please help. I've been trying to install skype for a very long time and I've tried countless fixes.

> UPDATE:
>   I can't install steam because of this either.

Comment: If you show us your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, someone may be able to explain how those lines are problematic.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 is not an LTS release.

Comment: Right sorry. Edited. And thank you but after I had breakfast this morning I did a fresh install and everything is working fine now.

Answer (score -2):

I had sometimes the same issue. I guess you can not install anything right? I fixed it with 2 solutions.

First try better mirror for updates.

> Finding fastest mirror from the graphical mode is very easy. All you to do is open Synaptic package Manager, go to Settings -> Repositories. From the Ubuntu Software section, Select “Other” in the “Download From” drop-down box, and click on Select Best Mirror.

[Source](http://www.unixmen.com/find-fastest-mirror-debian-derivatives/)

And second remove any ppa that is not working.

> Remove a PPA using a GUI: A PPA can also be removed by opening Software Sources (Ubuntu Software Center > Edit > Software Sources), then going to the "Other Software" tab, selecting the PPA you want to remove and then clicking the "Remove" button.
>
> Each PPA should have two lines here, one for the compiled packages and one for the source, so remove both lines.

[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/how-to-use-launchpad-ppa-add-remove.html)

One of these may help you.

Comment: Although your post may answer your question it is suggested to put the essential information from the links in your post rather than just the links.

Comment: I couldn't install Synaptic package manager because of the pre-existing problem and after removing all ppa it still gives me the same errors.

Comment: You have a malformed line in your `sources` file. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list

Comment: My fault, sorry! Edited

Comment: I didn't see this solution in time but when I woke up I tried a fresh install and it seems to be working fine now. Thanks for all your help!