# apt-get not updating and almost everything i try to install have issues with dependencies

Tags: software-sources

for the millionth time guys this isn't a duplicate question and if it is, them all the solutions don't work for me. i have seen this issue in a newly installed system. I tried all the things provided on the internet including creating a new sources.list, deleted the entries of list.d folder, but when I try to run the `apt-get update` command I get the following:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release 
Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

here is the sources.list

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe restricted    multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe main multiverse restricted

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe main multiverse restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe main multiverse restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports universe main multiverse restricted

# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Comment: sorry for the typos, have been up for hours now and i am really tired. its sources.list. i even forget the etiquette of saying please. anyway guys please help me out..

Comment: @pilot6 trust me it ain't a duplicate. have replaced the sources.list a million times with the same error. maybe there is another way you can assist.

Comment: Maybe you want to modify (click edit) your question to include the sources.list file

Comment: @Bruni seems like i can't post the content of the file..i need some reputation

Comment: @wachiranicholus You can just [edit] your question and add the content of the file. You may open it with your favourite text editor to get the content, or you may dump it in the terminal using the `cat` command: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and copy from there by selecting the text with the mouse and using right-click/copy (context menu) or STRG+INS. Do not use STRG+C!.

Answer (score 0):

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release
```

as the warning suggests its unable to fetch that url. Its your network issue. Not a source.list issue. Check if you have a working internet connection. Are you on a network that needs you to set proxy manually ? In such cases `sudo apt-get update` fails if proxy is not set properly for the sudo environment.

Comment: if it was a network issue i don't see how it can fetch other urls and fail with that specific one sir. ..ping works fyn anyways..thanks for the attempt i can use another brainstorm from you though..

Comment: could you please send a full log the `update command` and the output , and  result of the command `curl http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release -o /tmp/aucr123`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
   alther the sources.list file whit gedit
```

and then type this in the bottom

```
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release
   # deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/trusty/Release
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: as you can see there is no entry of `deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/trusty/Release` or `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release` in my sources.list maybe it is related to another url in there its not one of the ones available.

Comment: Delete the sources.list file and use the other sources file, and simple rename it to sources.list.

Answer (score -2):

Use this

```
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release
```

Instead of this

```
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release
```

or Change DNS to google DNS or Open DNS

Goolge DNS

> 8.8.8.8
>
> 8.8.4.4

Openn DNS

> 208.67.222.222
>
> 208.67.220.220

or you still face problem see this Community help

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu
```

Comment: Why? `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release` is valid too.

Comment: that address in the error is not in my sources.list file. how do i use the address you advised?

Comment: Yes @Oli Its Valid address but some time DNS does not resolve address.....thats why i suggest to use http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release

Comment: @wachiranicholus

please add the link in your source list

Open terminal 

sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list

and add the following line 

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release

or just put us before archive

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release

Comment: @Rai thanks for the replies but how to i use the address, append it the sources.list or what?

Comment: If the old host was not reachable, the error would have been different. According to Oli, this will not change anything. It's the syntax of the sources.list file that is wrong and not the used address!

Comment: edit source list file with gedit editor

path = /etc/apt/sources.list

just put (us) in following un commented (#) line in file 

like this 

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release without comment

change this too 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release

Comment: but first change DNS

Comment: @Rai thanks for the replies, i have added the address in the sources.list but when i try to update it returns an error about a malformed line 13 in the sources.list file. have tried several tweaks on the address but it doesn't work

Comment: @wachiranicholus 

see this-----------> http://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list

Comment: @Rai have tried those suggestions and none works