# Error in software updater

Tags: 15.04

this is Noah,I recently installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my acer aspireV7 and after uninstalling my software-center i am now getting this error"(E:Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtual.list(dist))"

please help,thanks.

Comment: i got that error while trying to reinstall the software center

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
open a terminal by pressing the following keys simultaneously; ctrl, alt, t,
then enter the following:

(if you want to paste in the terminal you need to use ctrl, shift, v ).

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

press enter.

This will reinstall all default packages.

Comment: hey I tried that but all I'm getting is 
'E: unable to locate package Ubuntu-desktop'

Comment: Have you read and tried this?  
http://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list

Comment: Have you tried running  synaptic for package upgrades and info on broken of missing packages?

Comment: You are welcome; A pleasure to help.