# sources list path error - how to reset it?

Tags: software-sources, owncloud-server

Ubuntu Server 15.10
I think this might have occurred during the owncloud config process.

After login theres a message stating:

```
find: `/etc/apt//sources.list': No such file or directory
```

I would expect the path should be `/etc/apt/sources.list`

How can I correct that?

Answer (score 0):

Go to /etc/apt folder. Check what happened to the original sources.list file. If installing OwnCloud renamed your sources.list file, then simply rename it back. Also, check if the sources.list file was damagingly modified - if so, then delete it and generate a new sources.list file.
 
 If your sources.list file was deleted, then I suggest you generate another sources.list file using [this](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) website. And then put that file in /etc/apt. 
If you want more information about this then here is the [official Ubuntu Documentation about sources.list](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man5/sources.list.5.html) and a [related question on Ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=8559). I suggest you read them first before proceeding. 
 Hope this helps. :D

Comment: [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list) is another resource in case things go wrong.

Comment: Thanks linuxode. Had a look and sources.list is there, looks okay. I thought that '//' bit indicated the path was wrong, so was unable to find it?

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's the problem. If updating and installing software is alright, then there is no problem and you can safely ignore the message.

Comment: And of course, if I helped, mark this as an answer. :D