# I cannot install any software on my freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: apt, software-installation, 16.04, lts

I am new to Ubuntu and so far not having a very pleasant user experience. I have tried to install multiple programs but no luck. The software "app" does not work and I get an error of `Failed to load the package list`, followed by details:

```
E:Malformed entry 54 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Suite),  
E:The list of sources could not be read.
```

I have tried appending repositories in the apt list file but that is not working. I am at my wits end.
Please help.

Comment: See [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- First of all run `sudo apt-get update` and check if the problems persists

2- Maybe the repository is disabled.

You can enable it in the grafical way, going to settings and then ubuntu software
You will see something like this

[image]
check them.

You can also enable then in command line. Press ctrl + alt + t and:
`sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe restricted multiverse"`

Source: [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to clear up the 'partial' error first. Be very careful with these commands:

```
sudo rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/* # Remove files in 'partial'
sudo rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/* # Remove package lists in 'lists'
sudo apt-get update
```

If you are still getting a 'status' error, try restoring a backup copy of the file:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status.0715
sudo cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status
sudo apt-get update
```