# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS software centre not working

Tags: 16.04

I tried reinstalling gnome software but failed to do so.

Screen-shot of terminal:

[image]

please post a solution for this.

Comment: My be tho following link can help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list

Answer (score 1):

Do the following in terminal after you became root by `sudo su`. You can copy and paste (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>)the following block in one piece to your terminal and hit enter once to finish it and be back at your normal user:

```bsh
mv /etc/apt/sources.list{,.repairbackup}
cat > /etc/apt/sources.list << EOF
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1)]/ xenial main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
EOF
exit
```

This will whilst fixing your problem turn on all repositories and remove possible added repositories which have an entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list` this why this procedure saves your before existing `sources.list` file to `sources.list.repairbackup` so you can look at them and find the error. To add or remove repositories from this list please use the System Settings dialog for that.

Comment: Maybe `gksudo gedit` will be easier for a new user?

Comment: May be but harder to explain the solution in detail, beside `gksudo` is not installed by default and would need to install another package which is at the current situation maybe not even possible due to the malformations in `sources.list`. This is why i proposed this solution.