# How to upgrade Ubuntu with unofficial software

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade

I want to upgrade to 16.4 LTS and get the following message:

[image]

What can I do?

I am wondering if I have enough space. It's a netbook with 2GB RAM and 16GB SSD. The processor is Intel® Atom™ CPU N270 @ 1.60GHz × 2.

I might have unofficial software but how do I know? How can I then remove them?

```
 lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-2.0-ia32:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-ia32:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-ia32:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-ia32:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-ia32:core-4.1-noarch:security-4.0-ia32:security-4.0-noarch:security-4.1-ia32:security-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

sudo apt-get update
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                 
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                        
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                            
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [65.9 kB]             
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Get:2 http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg [72 B]                       
Get:3 http://deb.opera.com stable InRelease [2,592 B]                          
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Err http://deb.opera.com stable InRelease                                      

Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                       
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                               
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease [65.9 kB]            
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                               
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [380 kB]           
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                           
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [5,360 B]    
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [160 kB]       
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [7,137 B]    
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [840 kB]     
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_CA                     
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_CA                        
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [15.6 kB]
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_CA                
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [369 kB]
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                        
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [15.2 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                               
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [118 kB]         
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources [4,064 B]  
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [38.0 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources [2,760 B]  
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages [477 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages [12.7 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages [131 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages [5,178 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_CA                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_CA      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en         
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_CA              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_CA              
Fetched 2,714 kB in 29s (93.1 kB/s)                                            
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://deb.opera.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 63F7D4AFF6D61D45

W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
1397BC53640DB551
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
1397BC53640DB551
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
1397BC53640DB551
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.opera.com/opera/dists/stable/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libntdb1 python-ntdb
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bcmwl-kernel-source gir1.2-gtk-3.0 libgail-3-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin
  libgtk-3-common libmm-glib0 libnautilus-extension1a libunity-2d-private0
  libunity-core-6.0-9 modemmanager nautilus nautilus-data oneconf
  oneconf-common python-oneconf python3-oneconf unity unity-2d unity-2d-common
  unity-2d-panel unity-2d-shell unity-2d-spread unity-services
24 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/7,029 kB of archives.
After this operation, 115 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 406869 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgtk-3-common_3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6_all.deb ...
Unpacking libgtk-3-common (3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6) over (3.10.8-0ubuntu1.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libgail-3-0_3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgail-3-0:i386 (3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6) over (3.10.8-0ubuntu1.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libgtk-3-0_3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgtk-3-0:i386 (3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6) over (3.10.8-0ubuntu1.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libmm-glib0_1.0.0-2ubuntu1.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libmm-glib0:i386 (1.0.0-2ubuntu1.1) over (1.0.0-2ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu0.2_i386.deb ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu0.2) over (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../gir1.2-gtk-3.0_3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6_i386.deb ...
Unpacking gir1.2-gtk-3.0 (3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6) over (3.10.8-0ubuntu1.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libgtk-3-bin_3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6_i386.deb ...
Leaving 'diversion of /usr/sbin/update-icon-caches to /usr/sbin/update-icon-caches.gtk2 by libgtk-3-bin'
Leaving 'diversion of /usr/share/man/man8/update-icon-caches.8.gz to /usr/share/man/man8/update-icon-caches.gtk2.8.gz by libgtk-3-bin'
Unpacking libgtk-3-bin (3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6) over (3.10.8-0ubuntu1.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libnautilus-extension1a_1%3a3.10.1-0ubuntu9.11_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnautilus-extension1a (1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.11) over (1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.10) ...
Preparing to unpack .../unity_7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking unity (7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1) over (7.2.6+14.04.20151021-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libunity-core-6.0-9_7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libunity-core-6.0-9 (7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1) over (7.2.6+14.04.20151021-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../unity-services_7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking unity-services (7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1) over (7.2.6+14.04.20151021-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libunity-2d-private0_7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libunity-2d-private0 (7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1) over (7.2.6+14.04.20151021-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../modemmanager_1.0.0-2ubuntu1.1_i386.deb ...
modemmanager stop/waiting
Unpacking modemmanager (1.0.0-2ubuntu1.1) over (1.0.0-2ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../nautilus-data_1%3a3.10.1-0ubuntu9.11_all.deb ...
Unpacking nautilus-data (1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.11) over (1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.10) ...
Preparing to unpack .../nautilus_1%3a3.10.1-0ubuntu9.11_i386.deb ...
Unpacking nautilus (1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.11) over (1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.10) ...
Preparing to unpack .../unity-2d_7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking unity-2d (7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1) over (7.2.6+14.04.20151021-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../unity-2d-common_7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking unity-2d-common (7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1) over (7.2.6+14.04.20151021-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../unity-2d-panel_7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking unity-2d-panel (7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1) over (7.2.6+14.04.20151021-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../unity-2d-shell_7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking unity-2d-shell (7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1) over (7.2.6+14.04.20151021-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../unity-2d-spread_7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking unity-2d-spread (7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1) over (7.2.6+14.04.20151021-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../oneconf-common_0.3.7.14.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking oneconf-common (0.3.7.14.04.1) over (0.3.7) ...
Preparing to unpack .../python3-oneconf_0.3.7.14.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-oneconf (0.3.7.14.04.1) over (0.3.7) ...
Preparing to unpack .../oneconf_0.3.7.14.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking oneconf (0.3.7.14.04.1) over (0.3.7) ...
Preparing to unpack .../python-oneconf_0.3.7.14.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-oneconf (0.3.7.14.04.1) over (0.3.7) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.40.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for gconf2 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.46ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libgtk-3-common (3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6) ...
Setting up libgtk-3-0:i386 (3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6) ...
Setting up libgail-3-0:i386 (3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6) ...
Setting up libmm-glib0:i386 (1.0.0-2ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu0.2) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.248+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 3.13.0-92-generic
Building for architecture i686
Building initial module for 3.13.0-92-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up gir1.2-gtk-3.0 (3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6) ...
Setting up libgtk-3-bin (3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6) ...
Setting up libnautilus-extension1a (1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.11) ...
Setting up unity-services (7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libunity-core-6.0-9 (7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up unity (7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libunity-2d-private0 (7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up modemmanager (1.0.0-2ubuntu1.1) ...
modemmanager start/running, process 4900
Setting up nautilus-data (1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.11) ...
Setting up nautilus (1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.11) ...
Setting up unity-2d (7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up unity-2d-common (7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up unity-2d-panel (7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up unity-2d-shell (7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up unity-2d-spread (7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up oneconf-common (0.3.7.14.04.1) ...
Setting up python3-oneconf (0.3.7.14.04.1) ...
Setting up oneconf (0.3.7.14.04.1) ...
Setting up python-oneconf (0.3.7.14.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.9) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-92-generic
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.46ubuntu1) ...


sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libntdb1 python-ntdb
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 206 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 406874 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing python-ntdb (1.0-2ubuntu1) ...
Removing libntdb1:i386 (1.0-2ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.9) ...
```

[image]

[image]

```
sudo apt-get update
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [65.9 kB]
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release          
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                       
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease [65.9 kB]      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                           
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [380 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [5,360 B]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [160 kB]
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_CA                   
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [7,137 B]
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [840 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [15.6 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [369 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [15.2 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en [423 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en [7,661 B]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en [3,699 B]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en [193 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [118 kB]         
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources [4,064 B]  
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [38.0 kB]    
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources [2,760 B]  
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages [477 kB]   
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages [12.7 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages [131 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages [5,178 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_CA         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_CA     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en        
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_CA              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_CA              
Fetched 3,339 kB in 30s (108 kB/s)                                             
Reading package lists... Done
```

Basically the errors are following:
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                                                       Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_CA

and

Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_CA

Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_CA

Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_CA
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_CA

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_CA

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_CA

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_CA

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_CA

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_CA

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the outputs of the terminal commands `lsb_release -a`, `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: It appears that you have problems with several repositories you have added somewhere along the way.  Specifically, at least the opera and google chrome repos (maybe more).  You could try removing these repos and trying a `sudo apt-get update`.  If you don't get errors, you should be able to proceed.

Comment: How do I proceed to remove the repos?

Comment: open the software and updates from setting menu , there you can find the ppa's in Software Sources tab , you can also remove ppa's by removing the .list files from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory.

Comment: Sorry I am not particularly advanced. I posted a screenshot of sofware and updates in my my last edit. Can I remove from there and which ones should I remove and what are the implications of removing repositories?

Comment: I would suggest removing all 3rd party repos.  In other words,  on the screen you posted uncheck all the boxes after the first one. The upgrader would eventually do that anyway.  The implication is that the apps installed from those repos will not receive updates in the future.  But if their repos exist in the upgraded system, you can go back in and enable them.

Comment: I have unchecked all except the 2 as seen on the screenshot I just posted in my edit. However the remove box is not active any more. Should I just try upgrading now?

Comment: in a terminal issue the command `sudo apt-get update` and enter your password when prompted.  If you don't get any errors, you can try upgrading.

Comment: I did this, I did not see any errors, I tried to upgrade but I got the same error message as at the beginning of my post. I edited the output of "sudo apt-get update".

Comment: You got the same error message? Including this one? Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

Comment: No, I meant that I entered "sudo apt-get update", could not see any error, tried to upgrade again and got again the following unresolvable error message: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YMQl4.jpg

Comment: Consider trying the upgrade in a terminal by typing `sudo do-release-upgrade` that should at least show you the error messages.

Comment: I did sudo do-release-upgrade and wanted to post the output but my post size is limited to 30000 characters. Where can I post the output to get a new diagnostic?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43573/discussion-between-thierry-msika-and-organic-marble).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)