# Malformed lines

Tags: software-center, software-sources

whenever I try to install something or either use Software center or apply an update, I got error 'E: Malformed line 56 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist)'. I have already consulted this thread
[How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list), for example... but whatever I had done, the problem continued to exist. May I feel free and post a http://paste.ubuntu.com/22934876/, so some of you could see what does go wrong?

Comment: We have to see the contents of your `sources.list` file.  You should edit your question to include them.

Comment: Edited. I posted a whole file, I don't see anything wrong with line 56 :( 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See lines 56 and 57:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ partner
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner
```

They are missing a parameter the other lines do have "precise".

Use an editor to remove the 2 lines since lines 58 and 59 already are the correct versions of these 2.

Answer (score 0):

Both lines 56 and 57 are not ok.  The correct syntax is:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
```

The correct lines are 50 and 51 but they are commented out.  Delete the incorrect ones and remove the **#** from the beginning of 50 and 51.  Lines 58 and 59 should be removed too.  They are incorrect too.  Lines 50 and 51 cover all of them.

Answer (score 0):

i already did something to where the text editor doesnt come up the same but you are supposed to put these command first.

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/source.list  /etc/apt/source.list.old 
sudo cat -n /etc/apt/source.list | grep 2
sudo gedit /etc/apt/source.list
```

on the second command right where it says "grep 2" you are supposed to put the number of lines you have that are malformed into the command. and i believe you are supposed to put a number sine where the link starts in the test editor followed but a space and then hit save. on your terminal it should say something like this..

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/apt/source.list
** (gedit:3452): WARNING **: 21:16:30.900: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-position not supported
```

once it does that exit out of text editor and start a new terminal and start a apt-update && upgrade to see if you can source code an update.