# I failed to update in terminal in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, apt, software-installation

Im trying to update to install hevc player in ubuntu but it is not working always i'm getting the same output anybody please help me!!!

```
sudarsan@sudarsan-Inspiron-3551:~$ sudo apt-get update
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list (dist)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: What is the output? What command are you running?

Comment: sudarsan@sudarsan-Inspiron-3551:~$ sudo apt-get update
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list (dist)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: Edit your question to include this... in terminal, type `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list`. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0):

Open the file as super-user:

```
sudo nano -c /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
```

and make sure you are on line 1(you can see the line number in the terminal [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87uwl.png). Then, add the `#` at the beginning of line 1. When that is done, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. At the prompt, press <kbd>y</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then run `sudo apt-get update`.

Just note that:

> By commenting/removing the erroneous line the software won't be installed (if not already) or won't be updated/upgraded if that's what you try. Of which I suggest you to check where is that line coming from (which software requires it) and do the proper modifications as required in order to everything run fine.

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list#285018).

Comment: it's not working and the output  is  (gedit:8703): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

(gedit:8703): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
sudarsan@sudarsan-Inspiron-3551:~$ sudo apt-get update
E: Type 'trusty' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: I have updated my answer, in anticipation that gedit didn't open. If it did, did you add the `#` at the start of line 1 and save the file?

Comment: sudarsan@sudarsan-Inspiron-3551:~$ sudo apt-get update
E: Type 'trusty' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: Alright, it looks like the `virtualbox` package is problematic. Remove it with `sudo apt-get --purge remove virtualbox`.

Comment: sudarsan@sudarsan-Inspiron-3551:~$ sudo apt-get update
N: Ignoring file 'virtualbox.list.save.2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'virtualbox.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Type 'trusty' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
1

Comment: @TonyLancer why on earth would you tell the user to remove Virtualbox?

Comment: sudarsan@sudarsan-Inspiron-3551:~$  sudo apt-get --purge remove virtualbox
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Type 'trusty' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.