# Wrong source.list entry

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I was trying to use `sudo apt-get update` to update the packages on my system but I kept encountering an error

```
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/mongodb-org/3.4/Release  
Unable to find expected entry 'multiverse/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Error executing command, exiting
```

I looked everywhere, did whatever was suggested but nothing seems to work. I freshly created my source.list file but it was all in vain. Can anybody please suggest me something?

In my case not only a single line of sources.list if malformed but the entrie file is showing as malformed and I have already tried the methods suggested here [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list) but it is not working..

Answer (score 0):

I tried numerous ways to solve this problem, I even regenerated my source.list  multiple times but nothing worked. But later I realized that there wasnt any problem with my source.list file. The problem was that I had added another .list file(mongodb-org-3.4.list) in my /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory while trying to install mongodb which caused all this mayhem. Deleting that file solved my problem :)