# I cannot update ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt

I tried to update the OS, but I got the following messages:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                        
Hit:2 ttp://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Hit:3 ttps://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial InRelease                
Get:4 ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]       
Ign:5 ttp://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:6 ttp://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Err:8 ttp://ppa.launchpad.net/hzwhuang/ss-qt5/ubuntu xenial InRelease         
  Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (91.189.95.83), connection timed out
Err:9 ttp://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err:10 ttp://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Get:11 ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]    
Get:12 ttp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]     
Fetched 306 kB in 2min 8s (2,387 B/s)                                          
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch ttp://ppa.launchpad.net/hzwhuang/ss-qt5/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (91.189.95.83), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch ttp://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net: ttp:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What is confusing to me is that when I tried "ping" method from the terminal, the server appeared to work just fine:

```
$ ping ppa.launchpad.net
PING ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from haetae.canonical.com (91.189.95.83): icmp_seq=1 ttl=38 time=474 ms
64 bytes from haetae.canonical.com (91.189.95.83): icmp_seq=2 ttl=38 time=497 ms
64 bytes from haetae.canonical.com (91.189.95.83): icmp_seq=3 ttl=38 time=520 ms
64 bytes from haetae.canonical.com (91.189.95.83): icmp_seq=4 ttl=38 time=542 ms
64 bytes from haetae.canonical.com (91.189.95.83): icmp_seq=5 ttl=38
```

Can anyone help me figure out what is going on here?

Comment: I did not have enough credits to add more than two links and the system was preventing me from posting it unless I delete "h" from "http" in order for the system not to consider them to be links.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: If you're referring to the `ttp://` (without `h`) URLs, those may be because OP tried to circumvent the spam protection. Not all of them are malformed.

Comment: What's the output of `wget -O http://ppa.launchpad.net/hzwhuang/ss-qt5/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Here's the output:"wget:missing URL Usage:wget [OPETION]... [URL]...  Try 'wget --help' for more options."

Comment: @DavidFoerster One additional detail that I ignored is that "ping ppa.launchpad.net" returns a different address haetae.canonical.com. Why is this happening?

Comment: Oops, that should have been `wget -O /dev/null http://ppa.launchpad.net/hzwhuang/ss-qt5/ubuntu/dists/xenial‌​/InRelease`.

Comment: Concerning the output of `ping`, that's unrelated. Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Dear David, I have a new issue with my computer, see my post in this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/928900/mouse-and-keyboard-arent-working-after-upgrading. please help.

Comment: You have some erroneous paths in your sources. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)