# Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

Tags: apt, software-sources

My Ubuntu version is 14.0.4

I get the following error when I execute `apt-get update`.

```
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages [4,280 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en          
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release [11.9 kB]                      
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources [1,064 kB]                
Fetched 1,429 kB in 14s (102 kB/s)                                             
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  
 Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file 
 (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources
 Hash Sum mismatch
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: The entry is present and the file looks OK to me.  Did you try more than once?

Comment: @ubfan1 yes I tried more than 1 time and I always get this error!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error) and [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)