# Can't remove Sublime Text from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, apt, uninstall, update-manager, sublime-text

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I have the following message showing up in it :-

```
An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click from 
the right click window or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The 
error message was:'Error: Opening the cache (E:Malformed line 1 in source
list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list(type), E:the list of sources
could not be read.)'.
```

I have tried to remove Sublime Text by using Ubuntu Software and even by running `sudo apt-get remove sublime-text` in Terminal. But still I am unable to remove Sublime Text.

When I run `sudo apt-get update`, the following message shows up :-

```
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: run `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list` and lets see what the issue is...

Comment: check this please 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list

Comment: this what i get when i run your line  `deexit
ps://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
`