# how to remove kylin software-without Terminal

Tags: software-center, software-uninstall, kylin

i've downloaded the kylin-software. However I didn't install it right so it gave me this sign:

[image]

Now i cant find it anywhere and though i cant remove it as well as that Chinese dialog box keeps popping up every time i open or restart my device . I've tried to use the terminal with some of the suggestions to get it or remove it but the file isn't readable to remove or do anything![ The list of sources could not be read.]

Comment: I know nothing about Kylin-software, but you didn't say how you installed it (tarball, dpkg),  however your picture shows an error on line 46 of your sources. Have you edited the file & corrected the error (or at minimum made the line a comment by adding a '#" at the start of the line).

Comment: can you please give me a spisific command to use coz i donno what is line 46 !installed it from ubuntu software center as simple as i clicked on install botton though while installing internet got disconnected when i went through the ubuntu software i couldnt find the app to re install it or remove and the chinese dialog kept popping!

Comment: The line 46 came from your picture, and includes the file it says to edit & correct the error (/etc/apt/sources.list).  This is a line changed on your system by you, or someone since install (and not by clicking something on screen); either intentionally or because you've entered a command in your system that was incorrect (without understanding it & changing it to match your system).  I'd edit it with `sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list` but use whatever editor you know. Line 46 you have added needs to be changed to be a valid line (I can't know what it is) or commented out (so it gets ignored)

Comment: i tried that sudo apt remove <application_name> to remove it but its unlocated , i've tried the command u sent vim it gives me sudo: vim: command not found !!

Comment: I said I would edit it with `vim` (*i learnt vi in the 1980s; it worked on machines that didn't have arrow keys which were then still too common!*), and said to replace it with whatever editor you know & use.  You don't know or use `vim` and it's not easy for beginners, so use whatever editor you like (`nano`, `emacs`, `joe` etc)

Comment: problem solved thanks indeed for your support.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)

Comment: thanks for clarifying, i've checked the link before and it seems the same issue at first but when i went through i got even more errors thats why i had to ask.

Comment: Your problem was solved (you said), the comment was generated by the site when I flagged the page as a *duplicate*.  It's a step towards closing the 'thread'.

Comment: from **Software & updates > other Software** " found additional unclassified source codes that was the reason for the error" deleted them by clicking on **remove** button. restarted the system. made Ubuntu OS updates. then the UK kylin-software-center popped up again in Ubuntu-software. I removed it by clicking **Remove** button. then reinstalled it from the website itself (www.ubuntukylin.com) so i was able to choose the language of the app**Software** i prefer .but actually the kylin-software-center wasn't that helpful as i expected.

Comment: If the last comment was how you fixed it, I'd suggest writing that as an answer, and after the required-time-has-passed, you can accept it as your answer (you'll gain some reputation).  *Many people refer to those helpful in helping you find the answer, but that's up to you*.  As you gain more reputation on this site, what you can do here will grow.

Answer (score 0):

from **Software & updates > other Software** " found additional unclassified source codes that was the reason for the error" deleted them by clicking on **remove** button. restarted the system. made Ubuntu OS updates. then the UK kylin-software-center popped up again in Ubuntu-software. I removed it by clicking Remove button. then reinstalled it from the website itself www.ubuntukylin.com , the website is Chinese already so using some website translator would help to be more selective, and so i was able to choose the language of the appSoftware i prefer .but actually the kylin-software-center wasn't that helpful as i expected for **18.04.1** LTS