# How I can fix the error: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list (Component)?

Tags: apt, updates

I tried use remove malformed by doing follow this: [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list), but it's not successful.

And after I type: sudo apt update, the result is still not change:

This is:

E: The list of sources could not be read.

E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list (Component)

E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: Add the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list` to your post.

Comment: Can you help me how I add this content ?

Comment: (from the terminal) `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list`. Highlight everything, click the **edit** button (below your post), then paste.

Comment: It just displays: deb [arch=amd64] https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet-release/ yakkety main

Comment: How did you add this repo? What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I use 18.04 version!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97860/discussion-between-ajgringo619-and-know-dont).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the file with

```
 sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list
```

This repostitory is for 16.10, you are on 18.04 now.

According to https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet-release/dists/ there is no repository for 18.04 (bionic).