# Can't install Wine on ubuntu studio 19.10

Tags: software-installation, wine

So, I have Ubuntu Studio ver. 19.10. I'm trying to install Wine so I can run Windows VSTs (Toneforge, Odin II Guitar, Mjolnir Drums). However, whenever I type

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends wine-stable
```

I get the error

```
E: Malformed entry 58 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read
E: Malformed entry 58 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read
```

I also have the source, but I can't figure out how to build it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Edit /etc/apt/source.list and delete the line you should not have added.

```
 sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
```

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Del ,58, .... E: Malformed entry 58 in list.  /etc/apt/source.list

Comment: Delete how? Sorry, I'm new to Ubuntu.

Comment: completely string ...
https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list  Malformed entry 58 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)