# can not install wine on ubuntu studio 19.10

Tags: wine, ubuntu-studio

I tried checking for broken lines in `sources.list` and there seems to be none.
it just says `Malformed entry 57 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (component)
The list of sources could not be read.`

I am quite new to linux also
and I just insatlled it and don't have anything on my pc so I can reinstall it if I need to.

line 53 to 66 was this:

```
# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/eoan main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/eoan main
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ eoan main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ eoan main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ eoan main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ eoan main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ eoan main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/eoan main
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

`

Comment: sorry. I forgot to add dl. after https://
so it is `https://dl.winehq.org`

Comment: You need to use copy and paste - you've misspelt ubuntu on every single line -

Comment: ok I will do that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)

Comment: I did that but I don't see any malformed code there.

Comment: Spaces (white space so includes tabs) are used as delimiters, and thus matter

Comment: well the spaces are in the same places as in that list, so what could be the problem there? the space between the `https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/` and `eoan` or between `eoan` and `main`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces matter:

This one will fail:

```
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/eoan main
```

This one will succeed:

```
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ eoan main
```

See the difference?

Note that when you fix your typos, you might be replacing one problem (typo) with another (duplicate). Duplicates will also cause warning messages (not errors). Delete exact duplicates.

Comment: massive thank's!

Comment: I just realised I was doing something totally diffrent. I just did `sudo apt-get install wine` and it installed it right away.