# Error in downloading Wine in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, wine

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 and I want to install software with .exe but I read that I must download Wine so, when I try to follow the instruction of downloading wine it show me this error

```
"E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine-obs.list (Suite) "
```

when I run this commend

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
```

So what I can do?

Comment: This may help https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list

Comment: i check this before my problem is not the same

Comment: No , every command i wrote that it shows same error

Comment: You have a bad line in your sources list that is causing the error and preventing you from installing software. See this question for how to fix it https://askubuntu.com/q/78951/243321 Then first try the simplest and least dangerous way of installing wine. Do not add any ppas. See if the version in the Ubuntu repos works for you.  Just install `wine-stable`.