# Unable to install new apps after upgrading to 20.04

Tags: repository

I am not experienced in terminal operations in Ubuntu.

Whenever I try to add a repository I get a message:

```
E : Malformed entry 52 in list file etc/apt/sources.list
```

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

[How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)
this thread answered the questions that i had.
I am rather inexperienced in linux as well. I ran into the same issue as you after attempting to install WINE.
I did as one user suggested and used
sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list
to make edits while in the terminal. Then found line 52 in the sources list and removed it completely.
Then ran
sudo apt-get upgrade
just to make sure everything was fixed.