# sources.list file problem

Tags: apt

I've got a problem with my apt file sources.list. Whenever I'm trying to update or install something I keep getting this error and I don't know how to fix it. I tried using vi to remove the malformed line but it doesn't get deleted.

```
E: Malformed entry 58 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)

Comment: Also, instead of vi, try using: `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`. Nano is more beginner friendly.

Comment: Thank you! It worked!