# Broken PPA vreating havoc... Can't install PPA Purge or open software center. Please help!

Tags: apt, wine, ppa, purge

I have trouble with three of my PPAs. I stupidly installed some PPAs in order to install the newest version of Wine, not really knowing what I was doing and there is now a typo in some of them (I deleted a space character because I thought it wasn't supposed to be there). Now I can't open the software manager or install PPA purge. Using Mint 20.1.

Line 5 (and the following) in `additional-repositories.list`:

```
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/groovy main
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/focal main
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/bionic main
```

What I get in the terminal when I try installing ppa purge or when trying to open synaptic is:

```
E: Malformed entry 5 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Malformed entry 5 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Somehow I am supposed to be able to install PPA purge "manually". But I don't want to break anything more than I already have :) So I am asking for HELP! Please! :)

Thanks!

UPDATE:
I managed to correct the files, adding a space where it belongs. That allowed me to install PPA purge and open the software center again, yay!

Now I want to get rid of the PPAs: I understood using purge is best. but when I insert
`sudo ppa-purge ppa:wine-builds`
it doesn't work. Is that the correct PPA name?

Comment: So how does that "entry 5" look like in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list`?

Comment: Like this: deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/groovy main
But it shoild be: deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ groovy main
With a blank before groovy

Comment: And how does it compare to other entries in the same file?

Comment: So add that space and see if it helps.

Comment: And, well, after having tried for an hour, I found this, which helped: https://askubuntu.com/a/170798/1186180 Could have simply edited it in nano... I am just to new to this. Thanks anyway!

Comment: groovy, focal, and bionic are names for different releases. As far as I know, it's not good to have multiple releases among the sources? That may confuse the system?

Comment: One follow-up question.. when I do use sudo apt-get purge [package name], what exactly is the package name?

Comment: I suggest that you do not redact details about your actions or the terminal output.  So that we have complete information, you should edit your question and give us the entire command(s) that you are entering followed by the full, unredacted output of each command.  If you think there is a problem with a configuration file, please list the full path of the file and include the entire contents of the file.  Make sure that you use `monospace` formatting and retain all line breaks when telling us anything you're putting into, or getting out of a terminal

Comment: @Levente, exactly. Even though this was not my the initial issue, that's why I am trying to get rid of them all.. but after solving the first issue, I am still having trouble. See updated initial post...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)

Comment: Yes, I think (I hope) I got it now :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list in your terminal with

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list
```

Then replace all instances of groovy and bionic and replace them all with focal. Just a thought. I hope it works!

Comment: I hope this helps, though.

Comment: Yes, exactly... thanks all for the many, fast replies!

Comment: You are very welcome