# problems with the gcc-10-base architecture

Tags: apt, dpkg, synaptic

**The /var/lib/dpkg folders and files were mistakenly deleted. Almost all issues have been fixed except for the gcc-10-base architecture. The errors are:**

```
sudo apt update --fix-missing
[sudo] password for hugo:
Obj: 1 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40 / InRelease
Obj: 2 http://mirror.metrocast.net/ubuntu focal InRelease
Obj: 3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Obj: 4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+/ubuntu focal InRelease
Obj: 5 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease
Obj: 6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Obj: 7 http://mirror.metrocast.net/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Obj: 8 http://mirror.metrocast.net/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Obj: 9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Obj: 10 http://mirror.metrocast.net/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Obj: 11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/release/ubuntu focal InRelease
Obj: 12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu focal InRelease
Obj: 13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu focal InRelease
Obj: 14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/apps/ubuntu focal InRelease
Obj: 15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu focal InRelease
Reading package list ... Done
Creating dependency tree
Reading status information ... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run "apt list --upgradable" to see it.
N: Omitting the use of the configured file "main / binary-gcc-10-base / Packages" since the repository "http://mirror.metrocast.net/ubuntu focal InRelease" does not support the architecture "gcc-10-base »
N: Omitting the use of the configured file "restricted / binary-gcc-10-base / Packages" since the repository "http://mirror.metrocast.net/ubuntu focal InRelease" does not support the architecture "gcc-10-base »
N: Omitting the use of the configured file "universe / binary-gcc-10-base / Packages" since the repository "http://mirror.metrocast.net/ubuntu focal InRelease" does not support the architecture "gcc-10-base »
N: Omitting the use of the configured file "multiverse / binary-gcc-10-base / Packages" since the repository "http://mirror.metrocast.net/ubuntu focal InRelease" does not support the architecture "gcc-10-base »
N: Omitting the use of the configured file "main / binary-gcc-10-base / Packages" since the repository "http://ppa.launchpad.net/c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+/ubuntu focal InRelease" does not supports "gcc-10-base" architecture
N: Omitting the use of the configured file "main / binary-gcc-10-base / Packages" since the repository "https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease" does not support the "gcc -10-base »
N: Omitting the use of the configured file "partner / binary-gcc-10-base / Packages" since the repository "http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease" does not support the architecture "gcc-10-base »
N: Omitting the use of the configured file "main / binary-gcc-10-base / Packages" since the repository "http://mirror.metrocast.net/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease" does not support the architecture "gcc-10 -base"
N: Omitting the use of the configured file "restricted / binary-gcc-10-base / Packages" since the repository "http://mirror.metrocast.net/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease" does not support the architecture "gcc-10 -base"
N: Omitting the use of the configured file "universe / binary-gcc-10-base / Packages" since the repository "http://mirror.metrocast.net/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease" does not support the architecture "gcc-10 -base"
N: Omitting the use of the configured file "multiverse / binary-gcc-10-base / Packages" since the repository "http://mirror.metrocast.net/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease" does not support the architecture "gcc-10 -base"
N: Omitting the use of the configured file "main / binary-gcc-10-base / Packages" since the repository "http://mirror.metrocast.net/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease" does not support the architecture "gcc-10 -base"
N: Omitting the use of the configured file "restricted / binary-gcc-10-base / Packages" since the repository "http://mirror.metrocast.net/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease" does not support the architecture "gcc-10 -base"
N: Omitting the use of the configured file "universe / binary-gcc-10-base / Packages" since the repository "http://mirror.metrocast.net/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease" does not support the architecture "gcc-10 -base"
N: Omitting the use of the configured file "multiverse / binary-gcc-10-base / Packages" since the repository "http://mirror.metrocast.net/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease" does not support the architecture "gcc-10 -base"
N: Omitting the use of the configured file "main / binary-gcc-10-base / Packages" since the repository "http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease" does not support the architecture "gcc -10-base »
N: Omitting the use of the configured file "main / binary-gcc-10-base / Packages" since the repository "http://mirror.metrocast.net/ubuntu focal-security InRelease" does not support the architecture "gcc-10 -base"
N: Omitting the use of the configured file "restricted / binary-gcc-10-base / Packages
```

**How can i solve this problem?**

*User535733 gave me the following instruction: --remove-architecture*
**The architecture dpkg is buil for:**

```
sudo dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
sudo dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
gcc-10-base
i386
```

**When I gave the following order: dpkg-architecture -L this is the result**

```
dpkg-architecture -L
uclibc-linux-armel
uclibc-linux-i386
uclibc-linux-ia64
uclibc-linux-alpha
uclibc-linux-amd64
uclibc-linux-armeb
uclibc-linux-arm
uclibc-linux-arm64
uclibc-linux-avr32
uclibc-linux-hppa
uclibc-linux-m32r
uclibc-linux-m68k
uclibc-linux-mips
uclibc-linux-mipsel
uclibc-linux-mipsr6
uclibc-linux-mipsr6el
uclibc-linux-mips64
uclibc-linux-mips64el
uclibc-linux-mips64r6
uclibc-linux-mips64r6el
uclibc-linux-nios2
uclibc-linux-or1k
uclibc-linux-powerpc
uclibc-linux-powerpcel
uclibc-linux-ppc64
uclibc-linux-ppc64el
uclibc-linux-riscv64
uclibc-linux-s390
uclibc-linux-s390x
uclibc-linux-sh3
uclibc-linux-sh3eb
uclibc-linux-sh4
uclibc-linux-sh4eb
uclibc-linux-sparc
uclibc-linux-sparc64
uclibc-linux-tilegx
musl-linux-armhf
musl-linux-i386
musl-linux-ia64
musl-linux-alpha
musl-linux-amd64
musl-linux-armeb
musl-linux-arm
musl-linux-arm64
musl-linux-avr32
musl-linux-hppa
musl-linux-m32r
musl-linux-m68k
musl-linux-mips
musl-linux-mipsel
musl-linux-mipsr6
musl-linux-mipsr6el
musl-linux-mips64
musl-linux-mips64el
musl-linux-mips64r6
musl-linux-mips64r6el
musl-linux-nios2
musl-linux-or1k
musl-linux-powerpc
musl-linux-powerpcel
musl-linux-ppc64
musl-linux-ppc64el
musl-linux-riscv64
musl-linux-s390
musl-linux-s390x
musl-linux-sh3
musl-linux-sh3eb
musl-linux-sh4
musl-linux-sh4eb
musl-linux-sparc
musl-linux-sparc64
musl-linux-tilegx
armhf
armel
mipsn32
mipsn32el
mipsn32r6
mipsn32r6el
mips64
mips64el
mips64r6
mips64r6el
powerpcspe
x32
arm64ilp32
i386
ia64
alpha
amd64
armeb
arm
arm64
avr32
hppa
m32r
m68k
mips
mipsel
mipsr6
mipsr6el
nios2
or1k
powerpc
powerpcel
ppc64
ppc64el
riscv64
s390
s390x
sh3
sh3eb
sh4
sh4eb
sparc
sparc64
tilegx
kfreebsd-armhf
kfreebsd-i386
kfreebsd-ia64
kfreebsd-alpha
kfreebsd-amd64
kfreebsd-armeb
kfreebsd-arm
kfreebsd-arm64
kfreebsd-avr32
kfreebsd-hppa
kfreebsd-m32r
kfreebsd-m68k
kfreebsd-mips
kfreebsd-mipsel
kfreebsd-mipsr6
kfreebsd-mipsr6el
kfreebsd-mips64
kfreebsd-mips64el
kfreebsd-mips64r6
kfreebsd-mips64r6el
kfreebsd-nios2
kfreebsd-or1k
kfreebsd-powerpc
kfreebsd-powerpcel
kfreebsd-ppc64
kfreebsd-ppc64el
kfreebsd-riscv64
kfreebsd-s390
kfreebsd-s390x
kfreebsd-sh3
kfreebsd-sh3eb
kfreebsd-sh4
kfreebsd-sh4eb
kfreebsd-sparc
kfreebsd-sparc64
kfreebsd-tilegx
knetbsd-i386
knetbsd-ia64
knetbsd-alpha
knetbsd-amd64
knetbsd-armeb
knetbsd-arm
knetbsd-arm64
knetbsd-avr32
knetbsd-hppa
knetbsd-m32r
knetbsd-m68k
knetbsd-mips
knetbsd-mipsel
knetbsd-mipsr6
knetbsd-mipsr6el
knetbsd-mips64
knetbsd-mips64el
knetbsd-mips64r6
knetbsd-mips64r6el
knetbsd-nios2
knetbsd-or1k
knetbsd-powerpc
knetbsd-powerpcel
knetbsd-ppc64
knetbsd-ppc64el
knetbsd-riscv64
knetbsd-s390
knetbsd-s390x
knetbsd-sh3
knetbsd-sh3eb
knetbsd-sh4
knetbsd-sh4eb
knetbsd-sparc
knetbsd-sparc64
knetbsd-tilegx
kopensolaris-i386
kopensolaris-ia64
kopensolaris-alpha
kopensolaris-amd64
kopensolaris-armeb
kopensolaris-arm
kopensolaris-arm64
kopensolaris-avr32
kopensolaris-hppa
kopensolaris-m32r
kopensolaris-m68k
kopensolaris-mips
kopensolaris-mipsel
kopensolaris-mipsr6
kopensolaris-mipsr6el
kopensolaris-mips64
kopensolaris-mips64el
kopensolaris-mips64r6
kopensolaris-mips64r6el
kopensolaris-nios2
kopensolaris-or1k
kopensolaris-powerpc
kopensolaris-powerpcel
kopensolaris-ppc64
kopensolaris-ppc64el
kopensolaris-riscv64
kopensolaris-s390
kopensolaris-s390x
kopensolaris-sh3
kopensolaris-sh3eb
kopensolaris-sh4
kopensolaris-sh4eb
kopensolaris-sparc
kopensolaris-sparc64
kopensolaris-tilegx
hurd-i386
hurd-ia64
hurd-alpha
hurd-amd64
hurd-armeb
hurd-arm
hurd-arm64
hurd-avr32
hurd-hppa
hurd-m32r
hurd-m68k
hurd-mips
hurd-mipsel
hurd-mipsr6
hurd-mipsr6el
hurd-mips64
hurd-mips64el
hurd-mips64r6
hurd-mips64r6el
hurd-nios2
hurd-or1k
hurd-powerpc
hurd-powerpcel
hurd-ppc64
hurd-ppc64el
hurd-riscv64
hurd-s390
hurd-s390x
hurd-sh3
hurd-sh3eb
hurd-sh4
hurd-sh4eb
hurd-sparc
hurd-sparc64
hurd-tilegx
darwin-i386
darwin-ia64
darwin-alpha
darwin-amd64
darwin-armeb
darwin-arm
darwin-arm64
darwin-avr32
darwin-hppa
darwin-m32r
darwin-m68k
darwin-mips
darwin-mipsel
darwin-mipsr6
darwin-mipsr6el
darwin-mips64
darwin-mips64el
darwin-mips64r6
darwin-mips64r6el
darwin-nios2
darwin-or1k
darwin-powerpc
darwin-powerpcel
darwin-ppc64
darwin-ppc64el
darwin-riscv64
darwin-s390
darwin-s390x
darwin-sh3
darwin-sh3eb
darwin-sh4
darwin-sh4eb
darwin-sparc
darwin-sparc64
darwin-tilegx
dragonflybsd-i386
dragonflybsd-ia64
dragonflybsd-alpha
dragonflybsd-amd64
dragonflybsd-armeb
dragonflybsd-arm
dragonflybsd-arm64
dragonflybsd-avr32
dragonflybsd-hppa
dragonflybsd-m32r
dragonflybsd-m68k
dragonflybsd-mips
dragonflybsd-mipsel
dragonflybsd-mipsr6
dragonflybsd-mipsr6el
dragonflybsd-mips64
dragonflybsd-mips64el
dragonflybsd-mips64r6
dragonflybsd-mips64r6el
dragonflybsd-nios2
dragonflybsd-or1k
dragonflybsd-powerpc
dragonflybsd-powerpcel
dragonflybsd-ppc64
dragonflybsd-ppc64el
dragonflybsd-riscv64
dragonflybsd-s390
dragonflybsd-s390x
dragonflybsd-sh3
dragonflybsd-sh3eb
dragonflybsd-sh4
dragonflybsd-sh4eb
dragonflybsd-sparc
dragonflybsd-sparc64
dragonflybsd-tilegx
freebsd-i386
freebsd-ia64
freebsd-alpha
freebsd-amd64
freebsd-armeb
freebsd-arm
freebsd-arm64
freebsd-avr32
freebsd-hppa
freebsd-m32r
freebsd-m68k
freebsd-mips
freebsd-mipsel
freebsd-mipsr6
freebsd-mipsr6el
freebsd-mips64
freebsd-mips64el
freebsd-mips64r6
freebsd-mips64r6el
freebsd-nios2
freebsd-or1k
freebsd-powerpc
freebsd-powerpcel
freebsd-ppc64
freebsd-ppc64el
freebsd-riscv64
freebsd-s390
freebsd-s390x
freebsd-sh3
freebsd-sh3eb
freebsd-sh4
freebsd-sh4eb
freebsd-sparc
freebsd-sparc64
freebsd-tilegx
netbsd-i386
netbsd-ia64
netbsd-alpha
netbsd-amd64
netbsd-armeb
netbsd-arm
netbsd-arm64
netbsd-avr32
netbsd-hppa
netbsd-m32r
netbsd-m68k
netbsd-mips
netbsd-mipsel
netbsd-mipsr6
netbsd-mipsr6el
netbsd-mips64
netbsd-mips64el
netbsd-mips64r6
netbsd-mips64r6el
netbsd-nios2
netbsd-or1k
netbsd-powerpc
netbsd-powerpcel
netbsd-ppc64
netbsd-ppc64el
netbsd-riscv64
netbsd-s390
netbsd-s390x
netbsd-sh3
netbsd-sh3eb
netbsd-sh4
netbsd-sh4eb
netbsd-sparc
netbsd-sparc64
netbsd-tilegx
openbsd-i386
openbsd-ia64
openbsd-alpha
openbsd-amd64
openbsd-armeb
openbsd-arm
openbsd-arm64
openbsd-avr32
openbsd-hppa
openbsd-m32r
openbsd-m68k
openbsd-mips
openbsd-mipsel
openbsd-mipsr6
openbsd-mipsr6el
openbsd-mips64
openbsd-mips64el
openbsd-mips64r6
openbsd-mips64r6el
openbsd-nios2
openbsd-or1k
openbsd-powerpc
openbsd-powerpcel
openbsd-ppc64
openbsd-ppc64el
openbsd-riscv64
openbsd-s390
openbsd-s390x
openbsd-sh3
openbsd-sh3eb
openbsd-sh4
openbsd-sh4eb
openbsd-sparc
openbsd-sparc64
openbsd-tilegx
aix-i386
aix-ia64
aix-alpha
aix-amd64
aix-armeb
aix-arm
aix-arm64
aix-avr32
aix-hppa
aix-m32r
aix-m68k
aix-mips
aix-mipsel
aix-mipsr6
aix-mipsr6el
aix-mips64
aix-mips64el
aix-mips64r6
aix-mips64r6el
aix-nios2
aix-or1k
aix-powerpc
aix-powerpcel
aix-ppc64
aix-ppc64el
aix-riscv64
aix-s390
aix-s390x
aix-sh3
aix-sh3eb
aix-sh4
aix-sh4eb
aix-sparc
aix-sparc64
aix-tilegx
solaris-i386
solaris-ia64
solaris-alpha
solaris-amd64
solaris-armeb
solaris-arm
solaris-arm64
solaris-avr32
solaris-hppa
solaris-m32r
solaris-m68k
solaris-mips
solaris-mipsel
solaris-mipsr6
solaris-mipsr6el
solaris-mips64
solaris-mips64el
solaris-mips64r6
solaris-mips64r6el
solaris-nios2
solaris-or1k
solaris-powerpc
solaris-powerpcel
solaris-ppc64
solaris-ppc64el
solaris-riscv64
solaris-s390
solaris-s390x
solaris-sh3
solaris-sh3eb
solaris-sh4
solaris-sh4eb
solaris-sparc
solaris-sparc64
solaris-tilegx
uclinux-armel
uclinux-i386
uclinux-ia64
uclinux-alpha
uclinux-amd64
uclinux-armeb
uclinux-arm
uclinux-arm64
uclinux-avr32
uclinux-hppa
uclinux-m32r
uclinux-m68k
uclinux-mips
uclinux-mipsel
uclinux-mipsr6
uclinux-mipsr6el
uclinux-mips64
uclinux-mips64el
uclinux-mips64r6
uclinux-mips64r6el
uclinux-nios2
uclinux-or1k
uclinux-powerpc
uclinux-powerpcel
uclinux-ppc64
uclinux-ppc64el
uclinux-riscv64
uclinux-s390
uclinux-s390x
uclinux-sh3
uclinux-sh3eb
uclinux-sh4
uclinux-sh4eb
uclinux-sparc
uclinux-sparc64
uclinux-tilegx
mint-m68k
```

**No information about gcc-10-base. Then how can I identify and remove the gcc-10-base architecture if it is not listed in the recognized architectures**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)

Comment: See `man dpkg`. Read the section on `--remove-architecture`