# How do I fix /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management

I was trying to install wine on my chromebook, when I encountered an issue. Currently when I try to execute any command I receive the error message:

```
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (type)
E: Type 'echo' is not known on line 5 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (type)
E: Type 'echo' is not known on line 5 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Because of this, I'm unable to install the nano editing software to fix whatever issue there may be. I've searched the internet for a solution for quite awhile and I'm not sure what to do at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## Edit

`sed -n 5p /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq.list` outputs `sed: can't read /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq.list: No such file or directory`

`head -n1 /etc/apt/sources.list` outputs `tee`

## Edit 2

The first command outputs nothing, and prompts a new entry (leading me to believe it worked considering there is a new error now.)

Running update leaves me with:

```
E: Malformed line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, primarily because my system currently does not have nano installed, and when I attempt to install nano i get the exact same error message I stated above.

Comment: Then add the full output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and `grep -r -v ^# /etc/apt//sources.list.d/ --include="*.list"` to the question. If long - use pastebin. What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: You can install [nano](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) manually, save it somewhere, and `dpkg -i nano_*.deb` from the command line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)

Comment: Boot up a live linux and repair the file from this live session.