# Malformed entry in sources.list after Impish upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade

There are a lot of answers related somewhat to this question, but doesn't seem to help as I didn't had this error before. This error came after upgrading to Ubuntu Impish from 21.04

```bsh
$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for kirti: 
E: Malformed entry 2 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list (Suite)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt impish-pgdg main
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/
impish-pgdg main
$
```

I had postgresql installed before update. Though, postgresql works fine I'm not able to perform certain tasks on terminal, let it be a simple `update`

Can somebody please help me?

pgdg.list:
[image]

**Also I don't know why by default it is selected as `postgresql` in ubuntu update.** 
[image]

Comment: Can you post the contents of `pgdg.list`? This will make it easier to spot the error 

Comment: I've added @matigo

Comment: Seems like sometime you tried to add the same source a second time...but made a typo. Line 1 is correct. Lines 2+3 say the same thing, but spread across two lines is the error. Simply delete lines 2 and 3.

Comment: No its' the same content, I wanted to show

Comment: Confused what you are trying to say. We cannot see nonverbal cues, so please try to be clear and unambiguous in your writing. Regardless, simply delete lines 2 and 3, then save the file.

Comment: You sure I should delete the 2 lines?

Comment: Alternately, you could simply comment those two lines out. Prepend a `#` on lines 2 and 3, then save.

Comment: Why that source is selected in your Software & Updates control panel is a different question. It's best to keep questions simple. The short answer is that the source is selected *because you use it*. Unselected sources are disabled (unused).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rewrite this sources.list file using single long command below:

```
cat << EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt impish-pgdg main
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ impish-pgdg main
EOF
```

Note that lines 2 and 3 are now one line with *deb* package type, its *url*, *version* and *component*. So it conforms with [normal correct sources.list style format](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/en/man5/sources.list.5.html#the%20deb%20and%20deb-src%20types:%20general%20format).

Then run `sudo apt-get update` again.