# Cannot remove architecture i386

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, architecture

i tried to install  WineHQ in my ubuntu 20.04 desktop

after the

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

that a video that i watched showed me i got some errors

now i cant install update the system

when i try to remove i386 with:

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386
```

it gives me the following error:

```
dpkg: error: cannot remove architecture 'i386' currently in use by the database
```

Please help me

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295241/dpkg-error-cannot-remove-architecture-i386-currently-in-use-by-the-database

Comment: @ChanganAuto nothing that this link said works for me

Comment: when i type ```sudo apt-get remove --purge `dpkg --get-selections | awk '/i386/{print $1}'`
```  it says: 

```E: Malformed entry 62 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Malformed entry 62 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: Read your output: Fix the 'malformed entry' error, then try again. If you don't understand what the 'malformed entry' error means or how to fix it, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951

Comment: @user535733 thanks it worked

Comment: but when i type sudo apt update it shows me an error: E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 3028 (aptd)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/

Comment: If you try the error text in the 'Search' box at the top of the page, it will suggest https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433. Advice: Learn the habit of looking up errors. We will happily help with obscure or unusual errors, but the problems you have encountered so far are very common new-user learning experiences.

Comment: oh sorry ok btw i fixed it