# I take eror when ı want to upgrade lubuntu, also when ı try to use package menager or terminal. On this sense, Im able to use almost nothing

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, lubuntu, error-handling

this for upgrade lubuntu

```
This is a serious problem. Try again later. If this problem appears again, please report an error to the developers.
Error Detail: E:Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_hirsute-impish.list (Component), E:Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_impish-impish.list (Component), E:The list of sources could not be read.
Failed to load the package list
This is a serious problem. Try again later. If this problem appears again, please report an error to the developers.
```

---

I got the same erors on terminal and package menager
it happened after try to download wine
but ı did exactly the thing they say on forum
so ı dont understand the problem, ı need help please.

---

after this happened, I tryed command of;

sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list

But it says command not found.

then ı did use

sudo sed -i -e '68d' /etc/apt/sources.list

---

sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list.backup /etc/apt/sources.list

---

sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list

-

on the smilar questions in the forum the ways people suggesting didnt helped until now . same eror continue...

I think it deleted some thing when ı use the command of;
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ impish main'

because just after ı dıd thıs, problem started.

Comment: There are lines in some of your source files that don't have the correct structure. Please check `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_hirsute-impish.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_impish-impish.list`, the first entry in each.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)

Comment: Also, please always post error messages in English. The people on this site mostly speak English, and if you throw any other language at them, it diminishes your chances to get help. If your question didn't happen to include an English version of the error message in addition to the Turkish version, I wouldn't have had any clue what could be the problem ;)

Comment: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_hirsute-impish.list    -- ı dıd but it says permisson denied , second one also same

Comment: the things on the question ı was tried before ask this question didnt worked everything they explain in this ı did and problem continues

Comment: and thank you for the advice ı wll remember this  :)

Comment: Regarding "permission denied", you need to edit the files as a privileged user, often also called "with root permissions" (because most systems have one privileged user called `root`). You may want to read up on the `sudo` command.

Answer (score 0):

Please note you've contributed to a problem probably significantly by your own admission; ie. commands like

- `sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`
- `sudo sed -i -e '68d' /etc/apt/sources.list`
- `sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list.backup /etc/apt/sources.list`
- `sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

as these are not the file created by your
`sudo add-apt-repository` command you mention that caused your issue.

A clean install has an empty `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and the `add-apt-repository` command creates entries in there as outlined in your error

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_hirsute-impish.list`

ie. to fix your issue, that is the file you should hae made correction(s) to. Now you need to undo whatever changes you made with the multiple edits of a valid file in your `sed` & multiple edit commands.  What you did in those edits we can't know as you didn't provide details; only the command that started the edit.

This is really a comment (*too long for comment though*) that may help you understand what is wrong.  Sorry I'd love to help, but the error in your question

```
E:Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_hirsute-impish.list
```

tells you what line number (1) and in what file (`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_hirsute-impish.list`) the correction needs to be made; which is not what you attempted. Duplicate links on this site tell you how to fix (or *comment out*) these errors.

Comment: that isn't written as an answer; duplicate link provides that..  It's written in hopes it's helpful to OP; and I was just too wordy for a real comment I'd have preferred