# How do I fix the Malformed Line in Source List?

Tags: apt, 20.04, sudo, spotify

I am getting the following error when running apt update after installing Spotify. I am new to Linux and I ran into this problem.

```
E: Malformed line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

[This is my source list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iE8fm.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list). Welcome! We ask that you search before asking because in many cases, a question has already been asked and answered. If you still need help you can start a new question. Share what you found in your research and tell us why it didn't work for you. When sharing text please copy/paste and use monospace formatting when applicable. Images of text are discouraged- it's hard to read and impossible to work with.

Comment: The error tells you the file which has the error, and line which contains it; what more help do you need?   Someone with `sudo` rights added the *incorrectly formatted* file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` as that directory is empty on a new install; and meta data should tell you who when it was added so you can chase up the culprit, or just fix it.  We cannot see the contents unless provided; but with a line number & filename that contains it - it should be easy to find.

Comment: @Nmath Thank you, I did looked at that link before and I was not able to fix it. For some reason guiverc comment helped. I opened the file /etc/apt/sources/list.d/ and was able to edit it. Thank you again.