# sudo apt-get update gives Error:Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ros

[Upon removing ROS, python and Realsense from my ubuntu 18.04 install, I was trying to update the lists before embarking on a fresh install when the below error occured.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmgOL.png)

[Below I followed the instructions in the link:https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list and made changes to the sources.list by uncommenting the deb-src lines.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gffew.png)

I then repeated sudo apt-get update and got the following output yet again:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHTnv.png)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please don't post screenshots of the terminal. Always copy the text from the terminal and [paste it directly in the question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1405024/edit). Then format the pasted text as `code` by clicking on the {_} icon above the edit window.

Comment: Read the error message: The error message contains a file and a location within that file. Open the file, look for the mistake or typo in that location, fix it, and then save the file. The changes you already made to a *different* file were likely pointless; undo those changes.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list` and indeed don't post sceenshots.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages **you** got on **your system**. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis. And, if you post text, rather than pictures of text, we can easily copy it to try locally.