# i cannot use my ubuntu desktop server anymore

Tags: software-installation

I was trying to install jellyfin and gave up half way through because I kept encountering an error I then rebooted my server and now when I try to install anything or update it I get this error

E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jellyfin.list ([option] no value) E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: fyi I'm new to server making and i followed the instillation tutorial for ubuntu to the T as well as the jellyfin install

Comment: Refer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list - this is a common issue and this post explains how to handle those cases.

Comment: A new install will have NO ENTRIES in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` thus that file has been added by someone with `sudo` privileges onto your system. They've however added an incorrectly formatted file, which has an error on line 1 of the filename provided in the message. That line causes subsequent lines to not be read (error is treated as end-of-file) so further errors may exist; but we can't see that file unless provided. Edit & correct that file.