# How to install easytag or Ex Falso on 20.04.5

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, metadata, easytag

When trying to install easytag I get the following error message:

Unable to install gnome-easytag: cannot perform the following tasks

Trying to install exfalso gives the following error message :

sudo apt install exfalso
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/balena-etcher.list (URI parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/balena-etcher.list (URI parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)

Comment: I'd apply all security fixes & updates to your system asap, as your details imply you're months behind on application of security updates. Refer https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/ for the ISO release date of 20.04.6, but installed systems upgraded before the ISO release.

Comment: I decided to upgrade to 22.04 butafter entering
sudo apt update
I got the same error
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/balena-etcher.list (URI parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: Fix or remove the bad line mentioned in the error message. It's in the file mentioned in the error message. If you don't know what is wrong with the line, edit your question and tell us what it is.

Comment: It seems https://deb.etcher.io is no longer available

Comment: Are there any currently available apps to edit metadata in .wav files?